# Atualizar dados em TextBox em componentes .ascx diferentes, mas que estão na mesma página .aspx

Tags: c#, vb.net, aspx

Mais uma vez necessitando da ajuda de vocês!

Seguinte, Tenho uma página `CadastroProposta.aspx`, dentro dessa página, são carregados 2 componentes customizados, `DadosPagamento.ascx` e `DadosCobranca.ascx`.

No componente `DadosPagamento.ascx`, tenho um `<asp:Button ID="btnConfirmar">` e um `<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumeroPropostaOrigem" runat="server">`.

No componente `DadosCobranca.ascx`, tenho um `<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumeroPropostaDestino" runat="server">`.

O que necessito é que ao clicar no `Button Confirmar (DadosPagamento.ascx)`, o valor que está na `TextBox de origem (DadosPagamento.ascx)`, apareça na `TextBox de Destino(DadosCobranca.ascx)`.

Já pesquisei muito sobre PostBack, mas não consegui implementar na minha aplicação.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, desde já agradeço muito!

Comment: Veja se era isso que você procurava. E edite a sua pergunta, apresentando o código de fato dos seus controles, isso facilita o entendimento do problema e a montar uma resposta para sua dúvida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No controle de origem, você implementar o evento de `delegate`, publicar a mensagem com o `MessageHandler` no click do botão. O controle de origem deve possuir um método público para tratar essa mensagem e você faz o bind de ambos no `parent` onde os controles foram incluídos, veja o exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**DadosPagamento.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DadosPagamento.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.Forms.DadosPagamento" %>
<h1>Dados de Pagamento</h1>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumeroPropostaOrigem" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirmar" runat="server" Text="Confirmar" OnClick="btnConfirmar_Click"/>
```

**DadosPagamento.ascx.cs**

```
public delegate void MessageHandler(string codigoProposta);
public partial class DadosPagamento : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event MessageHandler EnviarProposta;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }        


    protected void btnConfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnviarProposta(txtNumeroPropostaOrigem.Text);
        txtNumeroPropostaOrigem.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**DadosCobranca.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DadosCobranca.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.Forms.DadosCobranca" %>
<h1>Dados de Cobrança</h1>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumeroPropostaDestino" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**DadosCobranca.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class DadosCobranca : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void CarregarProposta(string codigoProposta)
    {
        txtNumeroPropostaDestino.Text = codigoProposta;
    }
}
```

**CadastroProposta.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CadastroProposta.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.Forms.CadastroProposta" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/DadosPagamento.ascx" TagPrefix="ucPagamento" TagName="DadosPagamento" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/DadosCobranca.ascx" TagPrefix="ucCobranca" TagName="DadosCobranca" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ucPagamento:DadosPagamento runat="server" id="DadosPagamento" />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div>
            <ucCobranca:DadosCobranca runat="server" id="DadosCobranca" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CadastroProposta.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class CadastroProposta : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DadosPagamento.EnviarProposta += m => DadosCobranca.CarregarProposta(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: na CadastroProposta.aspx é obrigatório colocar os componentes ascx dentro de um formulário? O meu está limpando a TextBox de Origem, mas não está populando a de Destino!

Comment: Todos os componentes asp.net precisam ser posicionados dentro de um `<form runat="server">` para seu funcionamento correto e só pode haver um por página. Seus controles de usuário não devem possuir outro formulário. E caso eles não estejam você não vai ter como utilizar o PostBack

Comment: @RenatoDamazio conseguiu resolver?

Comment: consegui resolver sim. Obrigado!!!